# Allure result not writing while run through command line

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, cucumber

SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.qameta.allure.AllureResultsWriteException: Could not write Allure test result

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the below video. It is very simple and easy way to implement allure.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjpSkaBq9c0
```